# read.xlsx 'Error in loadWorkbook(file): Cannot find file' R

Tags: r, file, r-xlsx

I am trying to read in a number of Excel files into R using `read.xlsx` using the `xlsx` package but when I do so I am getting the following error:

> Error in `loadWorkbook(file)` : Cannot find id100.xlsx

First I list the files in the directory:

```
> files <- list.files(datDir, pattern = ".xlsx")
```

Then I use `read.xlsx` to read them all in:

```
 for (i in seq_along(files)) {
    assign(paste("id", i, sep = "."), read.xlsx(files[i],1,as.data.frame=TRUE, 
    header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings=" "))
 }
```

I checked to see if the file was even in the list and it is:

```
> files
  [1] "id100.xlsx" "id101.xlsx" etc...

> files[1]
  [1] "id100.xlsx"
```

I have used this code many times before today and for some reason it is just not working. I keep getting that error. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: try this. `files <- list.files(datDir, pattern = ".xlsx",full.names=T)`

Comment: Are you sure you have loaded XLConnect?

Comment: Is your working directory, `datDir`? Also, make sure that both R and Excel are the same architecture(32-bit/64-bit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your working directory is different from datDir you should use `full.names=T` like this:

```
files <- list.files(datDir, pattern = ".xlsx",full.names=T)
```

Comment: Ugh, should've known that. Bone-headed mistake. Thank you!